# How to translate fortran goto state to matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

How to convert goto state(fortran) to matlab?
That means, if NOPN is equal 1, implement line 1,
NOPN is equal 2, implement line 2?

```
 subroutine VECT(N1,N2,N3,NOPN)

 COMMONS WORMX(3,24), QVALU,DJACB

   I1=N1
   GO TO (1,2,3,4,5),NOPN
 1 I1=N2
 2 QVALU=0.0
   DO 10 I=1=3
10 QVALU=QVALU+WORMX(I,N1)*WORMX(I,I1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have figured it out.  This is a "computed goto" -- from very old FORTRAN -- now deprecated.   The line numbers don't have to be `1,2,3...`.   They can be any valid line number ...   the Nth is selected from the list.